# All the APIs the laravel middleware is not working

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, middleware

I am using an auth middleware in laravel. If I am calling the routes which does not have `middleware('auth:api')` then it is working fine But routes under `middleware('auth:api')` not working.

I have tried to update htaccess file and tried approx all the solutions, but no results.

My Route code is -

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
Route::post('unregistered', 'API\InterestController@getUnregistered');
    Route::post('new-campaign-listing','API\CampaignController@new_campaign_list');

    Route::post('registered-campaign-listing','API\CampaignController@registered_campaign_list');

    Route::get('past-campaign-listing','API\CampaignController@past_campaign_list');
    Route::get('getcampaignhistory','API\CampaignController@getCampaignhistory');

    Route::post('register-for-campaign', 'API\CampaignController@register');
    Route::post('top-campaign-photos', 'API\CampaignController@topPhotos');


    Route::get('user-detail', 'API\PassportController@getdetails');

    //update profile
    Route::post('update-profile', 'API\PassportController@update_profile');





    //update profile


    Route::post('shared-post-data','API\CampaignController@shared_post_data');
    Route::post('vip-campaigns','API\CampaignController@vip_campaigns');
    Route::post('vip_client','API\CampaignController@vip_client');

    Route::post('add_user_interests', 'API\InterestController@add_user_interests');
    Route::get('user-interests', 'API\InterestController@user_interests');

    Route::post('update-user-interests', 'API\InterestController@update_user_interest');

    //polls
    Route::post('polls-for-vote', 'API\PollController@pollsForVote');
    Route::post('vote', 'API\PollController@vote');

    Route::post('contact-us', 'API\PassportController@contactmail');
    Route::get('campaignpostimage','API\PassportController@campaignpostimage');

    Route::post('firebase-token', 'API\PassportController@get_token');

    //notifications
    Route::post('notifications', 'API\InterestController@notifcations');

    Route::post('unread_notifications', 'API\InterestController@unreadNotifications');

    Route::get('coupons','API\CampaignController@coupons_list');
    Route::post('redeem','API\CampaignController@redeem_points');

    Route::post('campaign-detail','API\CampaignController@campaign_detail');
    Route::get('rewards_history','API\CampaignController@rewards_history');


});
```

My function in passportcontroller is :

```
public function getDetails()
    {
dd("hello");
}
```

My htaccess file code is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
#    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Even dd in controller is not printing. means API URL is not working

Comment: did you added `api` in the begging of URI, ex `http://localhost/api/user-detail` ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message?
Note:You should put the routes inside api.php

Comment: the error message is :
{
    "error": "Unauthenticated."
}

and yes all the apis are in api.php

Comment: You should send the token through header or as parameter like
example.com/api/?api_token=XXX.
or for header
Authentication : 'bearer  your Token'
to check if the user logged or didnot!
login first throught your api then take the token and put in your header

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more info about how you are consuming your API? 
if you are consuming the API's from different domain (Cross domain) than you will face the `CORS` issue, in that case you need to add the following [package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) to your laravel application

and if you are on same domain tha you can follow the 
[documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript).

In my case [this](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/810)
 git hub reported issue solved my problem

Comment: No No. I am hitting the api from the same domain